# Facebook Login Dialog pop-up blocked

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have searched this website for this problem but doesn't really point me in the right direction I want I should be doing with this problem as mine seems to be a bit more specific.

My FB JS dialog is being blocked by pop-up blocker in browsers, I know why because I'm not calling the FB.Login() function directly. Instead, I'm doing a series of checks before I ask for permission so it minimises the amount of calls push to the server and also, doesn't annoy the user.

What happens is that I only want to ask for this publish_actions permission if a certain set of conditions are met i.e.
 1. They are logged in
 2. It's not been asked before
 3. The cookie has passed the date to ask again

But it seems this is not possible.

Post comment button:

```
<input class="interaction-button-post" onclick="post_comment(4297,"OOS-4297");return false;" type="submit" value="Post">
```

The function to post comment to server-side with facebook login check:

```
function post_comment(card_cache_id,offset)
{
    // get content
    if(jQuery("#comment-form-"+offset).closest(".wall-card").hasClass("facebook"))
    {
       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected')
        {
            check_permissions();
        }
       });
    }
    //posts the comment to the database using ajax
}
    //ask permission and if granted, make post to update DB 
    function get_perms() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.authResponse && response.authResponse.grantedScopes.toLowerCase().indexOf("publish_actions") >= 0) {
                set_permission();
            }
            else {
                    date = new Date();
                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                    createCookie('fb-publish-actions', date + ',2', 365);
            }
        }, {scope:"publish_actions",
            auth_type: 'rerequest',
            return_scopes: true});
    }

    function set_permission(){
         jQuery.ajax({
                url         : "/social_networking/SetFbPermission",
                type        : 'POST',
                error       : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
                                console.log(xhr.status);          
                                console.log(thrownError);}
            });
    }
```

The below function basically reads a certain set of conditions. If a cookie doesn't exist, it will ask for FB permission, the date in the cookie is past the current date, it will ask for FB permission, only if it has been declined before. If the permission has been granted, then just carry on as normal.

```
    function check_permissions() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        if(readCookie('fb-publish-actions') != null)
        {
            thiscookie=readCookie('fb-publish-actions','0');
            aftersplit = thiscookie.split(",");
            fbJsonString = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < aftersplit.length; i++){
                        fbJsonString = {
                            "date" : aftersplit[0],
                            "count": aftersplit[1]
                        };
            }
            date = fbJsonString["date"];
        }
        else{
            date = currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate());
        }
        date = new Date(date);
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate());
        if(currentDate > date  || readCookie('fb-publish-actions') == null)
        {
            FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
                    var perms = response.data;
                    var exists = false;
                    for(var i=0;i<perms.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(perms[i].permission =='publish_actions')
                        {   
                            if(perms[i].status == 'declined')
                            {
                                if(readCookie('fb-publish-actions') == null)
                                {
                                    date = new Date();
                                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                                    createCookie('fb-publish-actions', date + ',2', 365);
                                }
                                else {
                                    count = fbJsonString["count"];
                                    console.log("something exists");
                                    date = new Date();
                                    date.setDate(date.getDate() + +count);
                                    if(count < 14)
                                    {
                                        createCookie('fb-publish-actions', date + ','+ (+count + +1), 365);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        createCookie('fb-publish-actions', date + ','+ count, 365);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else if(perms[i].status == 'granted')
                            {   
                                console.log("its granted");
                                exists=true;
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!exists)
                    {
                        get_perms();
                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

We have a commenting system so users can post comments on posts that are linked to Facebook and we would only like to ask for publish_actions permission on FB linked posts only.

Does this seem at all possible?

Comment: You have to call FB.login _directly_ on a user interaction (such as a click), otherwise it will be blocked by most popup blockers in default configuration. There is no way around this - because if there was, every spammer would use it too, to get their popups around the blocker as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this to work.

### TL;DR

- Pop-up windows **must** open on user-click, not called by another function or chain of functions
- Work out required conditions on page-load or before user click, minimises speed issues (if any)

---

So from what CBroe said, it made sense. I thought I must only show the Login() in the onClick part of the tag, **but only** if a certain set of conditions are set.

So basically, I did majority of the above on page-load and set two global flags. Then when the input button is getting generated, it will look at the two flags to see if they are true, then it will put Login() in onClick

Here's the code of what I did:

1. Set two global flags beginning of session, `ask` to determine whether to ask for permission or not, `loggedIn` to check if they are logged in to our FB app

   ```
   var ask;
   var loggedIn;
   ```
2. Runs these on page load, checkLoginStatus then after callback, check_permissions()

   ```
   jQuery(window).load(function(){

       checkLoginStatus(function() {
          if(loggedIn)
          {
               check_permissions();
          }
       });
   ```
3. `checkLoginStatus()` that provides callback:

   ```
   function checkLoginStatus(callback){
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
       (response.status === 'connected')? loggedIn=true : loggedIn=false;
       callback();
      });

   }
   ```
4. `check_permissions()` only runs if they are logged into FB, prevents some read errors in JS. In this function, multiple ask=false or true setters if conditions are met:

   ```
   function check_permissions() {
      if(currentDate > date  || readCookie('fb-publish-actions') == null)
      {
      FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
      var perms = response.data;
      ask=true;
      for(var i=0;i<perms.length;i++)
       {
       if(perms[i].permission =='publish_actions')
        {  
         if(perms[i].status == 'declined')
          {
          //ask is still true

          }
          else if(perms[i].status == 'granted')
          {    
           //ask is now false
           ask=false;
           }

                break;
                 }
               }
            });
      }
         else {
              //if date is still greater than current date, dont ask
                ask=false;
         }
       }

   }
   ```
5. And finally, code to determine add the login function or not:

   ```
       if(ask && loggedIn)
       {
           html+="     <input class='interaction-button-post' onclick='add_comment();get_perms();return false;' type='submit' value='Post'/>";
       }
       else {
           html+="     <input class='interaction-button-post' onclick='add_comment();return false;' type='submit' value='Post'/>";
       }
   }
   ```